# Add join filter in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am a novice in Laravel.

I want to add a filter join through Laravel Eloquent model.

I have below relationship

`user` belongs to `city`

`user` has one `restaurant`

`restaurant` has many `jobs`

Now I want to fetch all `jobs` with a filter of `city`.

I tried couple of ways, but ended up in error, like:

```
$jobs = Job::where("date_time", ">=", $currentDate)->where("city.id", 50)->whereIn('job_status', ['upcoming', 'active'])->orderBy('start_date_time', 'desc')->get();
```

and the below one

```
$jobs = Job::with(['restaurant'])->where("date_time", ">=", $currentDate)->where("city.id", 50)->whereIn('job_status', ['upcoming', 'active'])->orderBy('start_date_time', 'desc')->get();
```

So, here how can I add join from job -> restaurant -> user -> city?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have city_id in your table

```
 $jobs = DB::table('jobs')->with('restaurant')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'restaurant.user_id')
        ->join('cities', 'users.id', '=', 'cities.user_id')
        ->where("table_name.date_time", ">=", $currentDate)
        ->where("cities.id", 50)
        ->whereIn('job_status', ['upcoming', 'active'])
        ->orderBy('table_name.start_date_time', 'desc')->get();
```

I have edited my answer hope it helps. If not please post your errors and table structure.

You can read about joins here: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#joins

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.
Here, a job doesn't have a city, if you see the relationship
Job -> Restaurant -> User -> City
This the relationship.